# Read a iPhone log file content from Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos, swiftybeaver

How can I read a iPhone log file content from Mac?

I wanna read `/Library/Caches/swiftybeaver.log` in iPhone from my Macbook. The file log is generated by [SwiftyBeaver](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver)

Answer (score 7):

1. Connect your iPhone to your mac.
2. Open XCODE then select Devices and Simulators from Window Menu
3. Select your Application Package
4. Click on COG(Setting icon) and select download container
5. Save the file on Desktop or anywhere you want.
6. right click on downloaded file and select show package content
7. Access your log :)

for ref:

[image]

[image]
[image]